# How to get all hidden values from array of hidden field using J-Query

Tags: php, jquery

Hidden fields like -

```
    <input  type ="hidden" name="details[]" id="details[]" value="1"/>
    <input  type ="hidden" name="details[]" id="details[]" value="2"/>
    <input  type ="hidden" name="details[]" id="details[]" value="3"/>
```

Comment: You should have unique ids for html elements

Answer (score 1):

Are you get array Hidden field value bye id using jquery

```
<input type="hidden" name ="testdata[]" value="" id="testdata" />

<script> $(document).ready(function(){var singleValues = $( "#testdata" ).val(); alert(singleValues);});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var values = $('input[name="details[]"]').map(function(){
    return this.value
}).get();
```